# How to verify if an OWLDataRange object contains a specified value?

Tags: java, rdf, owl, protege, owl-api

I have an ontology created in Protege 4.3.0 and stored in an OWL file. Some data properties of this ontology have the their ranges defined as in the following expression:

```
({"absent"} or {"value1" , "value2" , "value3"})
```

I would search for the data properties which could have a specified value in their ranges, so I wrote the following code sample, but I do not know how to query an `OWLDataRange` object to see if it contains a specified value (for example the string `"value1"`).

```
final OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
final OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
final OWLReasonerFactory rf = new StructuralReasonerFactory();
final OWLReasoner reasoner = rf.createReasoner(ontology);

// ...

// iterate over all data properties
for (OWLDataProperty topDataProperty : reasoner.getTopDataPropertyNode()) {
    for(OWLDataProperty property: reasoner.getSubDataProperties(topDataProperty, false).getFlattened()) {

        // iterate over all data ranges for the current data property
        for (OWLDataRange dataRange : property.getRanges(ontology)) {

            // I would check if the current data property contains a specified value in their ranges.
            // ...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see from the docs (http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataRange.html) there are multiple types of a data range - in your case it's a `DATA_UNION_OF` that contains two `DATA_ONE_OF`. Thus, you have to handle those cases, either by some IF-ELSE (resp. SWITCH-CASE) branches, or a implementing the corresponding visitor (http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataRangeVisitor.html)

Comment: Where could I read an example implementing the `OWLDataRangeVisitor` interface?

Comment: And this is pretty easy to implement the interface. For your case, I guess it's enough to implement the boolean methods, i.e. for intersection, union, complement and then, finally, for the one of part which is the constructs that contains values.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this kind of problem is to use a reasoner ([This Pellet fork](https://github.com/Galigator/openllet) ).

The idea is to create a class that denote the 'individuals that have a data-property with the range to check' and another class that denote the 'individuals that have exaclty the property/literal'. Then using a reasoner you check if the intersection of thoses two class is non-empty.

As there is some tricks to get it work correctly here is my complete solution :

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;
import openllet.owlapi.*;

public class RangeInclusionTest
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        try (final OWLManagerGroup group = new OWLManagerGroup())
        {
            final OWLOntologyID ontId = OWLHelper.getVersion(IRI.create("http://test.org#entail-class-restrict-to-some-range"), 1.0);
            final OWLHelper owl = new OWLGenericTools(group, ontId, true);

            // This declaration is vital since this reasoner have problems with pure anonymous reasoning.
            // You can remove this property after yours tests, (or better use one of your already existing properties).
            final OWLDataProperty prop = OWL.DataProperty("http://test.org#dummyProp");
            owl.addAxiom(OWL.declaration(prop));

            final OWLLiteral un = OWL.constant(1);
            final OWLLiteral deux = OWL.constant(2);
            final OWLLiteral trois = OWL.constant(3);
            final OWLLiteral quatre = OWL.constant(4);
            final OWLDataRange dataRange = OWL.dataOr(OWL.oneOf(un), OWL.oneOf(deux), OWL.oneOf(trois));

            final BiFunction<OWLDataRange, OWLLiteral, Boolean> isIncludeInRange = //
                    (range, literal) -> owl.getReasoner().isSatisfiable(//
                            OWL.and(// You must be of all the following class
                                    OWL.some(prop, OWL.oneOf(literal)), // The class of the 'literal'
                                    OWL.some(prop, range), // The class of the range.
                                    OWL.max(prop, 1))// But you can have the property only once.
                    );

            System.out.println("[A] " + (isIncludeInRange.apply(dataRange, un)));
            System.out.println("[B] " + (isIncludeInRange.apply(dataRange, deux)));
            System.out.println("[C] " + (isIncludeInRange.apply(dataRange, trois)));
            System.out.println("[D] " + (isIncludeInRange.apply(dataRange, quatre)));

        } catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

First you must define yours ranges. Then use the 'isSatisfiable' method of the reasoner. One trick is to enforce usage of only one instance of the property by adding a restriction "OWL.max(prop, 1)" on the intersection class.

The output must be

```
[A] true
[B] true
[C] true
[D] false
```

Because the literal 'quatre' isn't include 'dataRange' the answer '[D]' is false.
As you can see this solution easilly allow tests inclusions of a range in another one.

A solution that do not requiere change on the ontology could have been to create a special swrl rule and check if an ontology (even empty) entail the rule, but currently no dl-reasoner support entailment on swrl.